# How to make a web page accessible only after scanning a QR code

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, web

Good day. I want to make a simple CRUD guest form system with Laravel. I want to make a web page containing a form that only can be accessed after scanning a QR code. Here is the flow:

User -> Scan QR code -> Access to web page -> Fill in the form -> Submit.

The problem is that after scanning a QR code the user will directed to that web page with a link shown to the public, making that the user can copy or save and access the link later without actually scanning the QR code again. This will let user to input their data even without being asked or scanning the QR, leading into a data redundancy in the database.

Is there any idea how can I make this to work? Or maybe another solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Add a token in QR image and submit the link with post route so user cannot access the page with get request.

Comment: You can set a session variable after scanning the QR code which can be used to access the webpage, and after submitting the form, you can clear that session variable so the user will have to face QR again.

Comment: If you're completely paranoid you can have an E-paper display with a QR code that changes every x minutes so people can't rip whatever URI/token out of it

Comment: @Mehrwarz - How would that even work? How would you make a QR code call a link using POST request with a token as data?

Comment: @AmirHussain - _"set a session variable after scanning the QR code"_ - How exactly would this work? Wouldn't the QR code need to contain a link to where the session is set? And couldn't they just save that link?

Comment: Use java script to send a post request with the token value captured from QR code. Lets say you want to play a sound when the QR is scanned. beside the sound call a function submitForm. In the function set the cuptured token as form input and submit is.
Can you tell me which library are you using for QR scanner?

Comment: @Mehrwarz - You can't control how the QR code is scanned, that's up to the client. Many people might even use a different device to scan the QR code (displaying it on a laptop/desktop and scanning it with a mobile) so where and how would you call that JavaScript?

Comment: @ZachJensz awww yeah... So stupid of me to even forget about this method. Maybe I will stick around with this method first. And wait for further reply(s) that maybe can be implemented in my system. Thank you.

Comment: @AmirHussain - Take a step back and think about it. You said _"set session after scanning QR code"_, can you explain _how_ you would know that the user has scanned the QR code? Remember that you have no idea what client or even what device they scan the code with. If the QR code contains the to link that creates the session, the user can simply save that link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a link with temporary lifetime and signed, you can create signed URL and use that. have a look at the documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#signed-urls

Comment: I should be a comment. It is not an answer.